# I attempted to draw columns with width of 100,but columns are not getting displayed

Tags: flutter, layout

This is the aim that is to be achieved:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yM6Kd.png)

This is my attempt to achieve the layout

```
return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor:Colors.teal,
      
      body:  
      Row(children: [
        Flexible(

child: 
 Column(

crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,

children: [
  Container(
    //height:double.infinity,
    height: 947,
    width:100,
    color:Colors.red
  )
],
 )

 ),
Expanded(
child: Column(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
  children: [
    Center(
      child:Container(
        width:100,height:100,
        color: Colors.yellow,
      )
    ),
    Center(
      child:Container(
        width:100,height:100,
        color: Colors.green,
      )
    )
  ],

)),
Flexible(child: 
Column(
crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
  children: [
  Container(
    width:100,
    color:Colors.blue
  )
],

)
)
      ],
      )
   );
```

Answer (score 0):

This way you can create the UI you want
Hope you know how to write a Stack Overflow question...

Find the size of the device

```
Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
```

```
  return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          width: size.width,
          height: size.height,
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[

              Flexible(
                flex: 1,
                child: Container(
                  width: 100,
                  height: size.height,
                  color: Colors.red,
                ),
              ),

              Flexible(
                flex: 3,
                child: Container(
                  width: size.width,
                  height: size.height,
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[

                      Center(
                        child: Container(
                          width: 100,
                          height: 100,
                          color: Colors.yellow,
                        )
                      ),

                      Center(
                          child: Container(
                            width: 100,
                            height: 100,
                            color: Colors.yellow.withOpacity(0.3),
                          )
                      ),

                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),

              Flexible(
                flex: 1,
                child: Container(
                  width: 100,
                  height: size.height,
                  color: Colors.blue,
                ),
              ),

            ],
          ),
        )
      ),
    );
```